# Using addToFolder and removeFromFolder in Alfresco document with CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm trying to use the document methods [`addToFolder`](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.9.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/FileableCmisObject.html) and [`removeFromFolder`](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.9.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/FileableCmisObject.html) in Alfresco via Chemistry CMIS Implementation with java.

I want to be accessible a document from multiples user spaces but I don't want to copy each one to each space. The document is generated bay a user and this user must decide if the document must be deleted, moved, modified, etc. But other users with read access to this space must read from its default spaces this documents.

So, from the other users I execute `myDocument.addToFolder(myNewUserSpace)` and this runs ok and I can access to it without problem. It is good.
But if due to some reason, I want to disassociate this myNewUserSpace in myDocument (using de myNewUserSpace proprietary user, not the myDocument user), I get an error due to write permissions on myDocument.

I don't want that every user that can execute `addToFolder`, gets write permissions too.

Is possible to do it without grants write permission on the primary user space?

Greetings.

Comment: You can create a "public" space (readable by everyone, or by one or more groups, ...)

Comment: No, I can't. The primaryFolder can only be accessed (read) by some little users, and nobody can write there except its owner.

Answer (score 1):

permissions can be inherited from a folder. Afaik addToFolder adds your spaceB as secondaryParent of myDocument, but permissions are only inherited from spaceA - the primaryParent of myDocument.

Comment: Yes, but if with userB I can `myDocument.addParent(spaceB)`, wouldn't  I can execute `myDocument.removeFromFolder(spaceB)` with this user too?. Now I can't do it although I grant write permission to userB on primaryParent. There isn't other way to do it?

Comment: you need Write permission on spaceB & myDocument to execute `myDocument.addParent(spaceB)` but afaik you need Delete permission on spaceB to execute `myDocument.removeFromFolder(spaceB)`
There are a bunch of opportunites to implement your use aces with custom code in Alfresco (behaviours or dynamic permissions) - you can still use CMIS to access Alfresco but you'll have to tweak Alfresco's internals for your use case

Comment: Yes, of course. userB needs and userB has delete permission on spaceB. But to run from userB `myDocument.removeFromFolder(spaceB)` Alfresco is requiring delete/write permission on primaryParent too. This is what I can't understand.

And referring to your suggestion, could you give me some documentation or example about how to do from Alfresco API directly?